# Java Help for my script test

Tags: java

I am VERY new and trying to learn Java. I have searched all google but cannot find a solution to my issue. I want my code to print out % java Shuffle1 a-b c-d but it only runs and says it is successful but there is NO printout. Here is my code:

```
public class Shuffle1 {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        int x = 3;
        x = x - 1;
        while (x > 0){                            
            x = x - 1;
            System.out.print("-");
            if (x > 2){
                System.out.print("a");
                if (x == 2){
                    System.out.print ("b c");
                    if (x == 1){
                        System.out.print ("d");   
                    }
                }
            }
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Later if-statements are nested in the earlier ones. This isn;t what you meant. Add a closing brace after each print, not just at the end of all the statements

Comment: Running your code, I get the output I expect, which is -- . Step through your code, and you will see that you set x to 3, you change it to 2, then you change it to 1, so you never enter your if (x>2) statement.

Comment: It would help if you told us the expected output.

Comment: Theis outputs is "--" (not successful), what do you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code. I could give you the actual code, but its better if you code it. :)   This doesn't give the answer that you want.. But this does teach you the how Java works in its simplest form.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        int x = 3;
         while (x > 0){             // as long as x is greater than 0, run this loop               
        System.out.print("-");     // always print "-". Because there is no printing condition specified. Is this what you want ??

        if (x > 2){
        System.out.print("a");
         }

       else if (x == 2){
            System.out.print ("b c");
           }

       else  if (x == 1){
             System.out.print ("d");

         } 
        x = x - 1;                      //always better to decrement x at the end 
}

}
```

Comment: Explaining why would be nice

Comment: @TimCastelijns - Trying.. trying... :)

Comment: @DavidWallace - So do I.. didn't mean that- actually. :P